# Safari Extension Distribute in App Store

Tags: ios, safari, xcode8, safari-extension

I have developed a safari extension using Xcode using javascript. I distributed the extension along with the parent app to appstore. But the parent app got rejected saying it contains just a blank view. The main functionality of the app is the app extension. Is there is a way in which I can only distribute the app extension using xcode without parent app.

I dont see a proper documentation in apple documents. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.